# Button for going to previous carousel item not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, carousel, glyphicons

```
<div class="row" style="padding-below:20px">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <img src="#">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h2 class="media-heading">
                                        Workshop/event name
                                    </h2>
                                    <p>Description in a few lines and click on more to see details of the workshop. Or maybe not keep the more button only.</p>
                                    <p><a  href="#"><button class="btn btn-info">More &raquo;</button></a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="#">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h2 class="media-heading">
                                        Workshop/event name
                                    </h2>
                                    <p>Description in a few lines and click on more to see details of the workshop. Or maybe not keep the more button only.</p>
                                    <p><a  href="#"><button class="btn btn-info">More &raquo;</button></a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="#">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h2 class="media-heading">
                                        Workshop/event name
                                    </h2>
                                    <p>Description in a few lines and click on more to see details of the workshop. Or maybe not keep the more button only.</p>
                                    <p><a  href="#"><button class="btn btn-info">More &raquo;</button></a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>Previous
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>Next
                        </a>
                        <div class="btn-group" id="cbuttons">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="cpause"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="cplay"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have made a carousel. However, the 'Previous' glyphicon arrow that should be clickable and move to the previous carousel item is not working. It is not displayed at all. Where is my code wrong? The button and glyphicon arrow used to pint to the next carousel item is working fine, but the 'Previous' one is not displayed only.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this below code.
 <!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item">
      <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="third-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Comment: You have to change this section <a class="left carousel-control" href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>

Comment: But my code for the 'Next' and 'Previous' buttons are exactly same, so why is it just showing the 'Next' arrow and button and not the 'Previous' one?